# Find matching the beginning in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

My collection: 
{
    "uri" : "test",
}
{
    "uri" : "secondtest",
}

My query: 
collection.find_one({
    'uri^': 'testdfhdfh'
})

Result: 0

My question: how find matching the beginning -

test

testdfhdfh

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
Try this:

```
collection.find_one({"uri" : {$regex : "{}.*".format(your_uri)}})
```

***Edited***

```
import re
collection.find()

test_uri = 'test/aaabbb'

for item in collection:
    if re.match(item['uri'], test_uri):
        print item
```

Comment: Warager, thanks but this not work: 

uri = 'test/aaabbb' 
result = collection.find_one({
            'uri': {
                '$regex': '{}.*'.format(uri)
            }
        })

Comment: Do you use the same collection as in example? If so you won't find any results because you have only 'test' and 'secondtest' uris

Comment: Looks like you try to find some element from your collection where uri value matches begining of your text. I think pymongo won't help you in it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to get this result, the value of which coincides with the beginning of my uri

Comment: I suggest you to get all values from collection, then iterate by one element and check match it or not

Comment: Try this import re
collection.find()

for item in collection:
    if re.match(item['uri'], text_uri):
        print item

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
result = collection.find_one({
  'uri': {
    '$regex': '{}'.format('test/aaabbb'[:???])
   }
})
```

But is there a way to get the length of this record (uri)